# Creating an async method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm writing javascript code to update the interface from the user.
This task has to be done in the background and shouldn't block anything.
The code is currently blocking/crashing the browser, the while loop is causing the issue.

What i would like is to wait till the checking and installing are complete and then perform other actions also in between. I want to avoid to write the scenario: TimeOut in a TimeOut in a TimeOut, which does work but it makes the code a mess.

```
updateChecking();

function updateChecking() {
    setTimeout(function() {

        if (settings.IsChecking === "True") {

            var isChecking = false;
            var isInstalling = false;

            // PROBLEM, Wait till checking is completed
            while (isChecking) {
                var timerUpdateChecker = setInterval(function() {
                    getIsCheckingUpdates().done(function(resultIsChecking) {

                        if (resultIsChecking === "False") {
                            isChecking = true;
                            clearInterval(timerUpdateChecker);
                        }
                    });
                }, 1000);

                checkForSystemUpdates();

                startCheckingDownloads();

                // PROBLEM, Wait till installing is completed
                while (isInstalling) {
                    setInstallerInterface();

                    var timerInstallChecker = setInterval(function() {

                        getIsInstallingUpdates().done(function(resultIsUpdating) {

                            if (resultIsUpdating === "False") {
                                isInstalling = true;
                                clearInterval(timerInstallChecker);
                            }
                        });
                    }, 1000);
                }

                viewUpdateInstalledAlert();

                getAvailableUpdates();

                unsetInstallerInterface();
            };
        }
    }, 0);
}
```

Any suggestions that could solve my issue?

Comment: Rerunning the checker every second using `setInterval` might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

`While` loops run until the condition if `false`. Now you're setting the variable to false and call while. So I'm not sure how the while will work. From what I understand it should be `while(!isChecking)`.

That said, you should maybe try to replace your `setTimeout` and `setInterval` and replace with `events`. You can create custom event, dispatch and listen. I think it would be much more efficient. Something like this:

```
var event = new Event('isInstalled');
```

In your installed function you dispatch the event:

```
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

And you listen to the event to trigger wanted functions.

```
window.addEventListener('isInstalled', function(){ 
    //whatever needs to happen when installed is done
})
```